# How to set a value in CHtml::textArea in yii

Tags: yii, textarea, yii-chtml

In my web application, I want to set a default value to CHtml::textArea.
In my view,

```
<?php echo CHtml::textArea('answer' . $no, '', array('rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50, 'class' => "form-control",'value'=>$exam->answer)); ?>
```

But, this is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it directly as the second parameter:

```
CHtml::textArea('answer' . $no, $exam->answer, array(
    'rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50, 'class' => "form-control")
);
```

See [CHtml::textArea](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#textArea-detail) for more details.